# How to Enforce Memory Limits on a Kubernetes Pod for a Shiny App Without Crashing?

Tags: kubernetes, shiny, deployment, out-of-memory

I'm running a Shiny application within a Kubernetes pod that performs calculations based on user input. For larger calculations, the app significantly increases its memory usage. Locally, on a laptop with 16GB of RAM, the app runs smoothly and manages to perform calculations without any crashes, effectively managing within the available memory constraints.

However, when deployed on a Kubernetes pod, allocated on a node with 32GB of RAM, the app attempts to consume more memory than allocated and crashes. This behavior occurs despite setting the memory limits in the Kubernetes deployment configuration, aiming to restrict the pod to use only a certain amount of memory. My goal is to ensure the pod operates within its allocated resources without attempting to claim more, similar to its local performance.

Is there a way to enforce a hard memory limit on a Kubernetes pod specifically for a Shiny app, ensuring it only uses the assigned resources without exceeding them and without crashing? The issue seems to be that on Kubernetes, the app does not adhere to the same memory usage efficiency as it does when running locally.

Could this be related to how Kubernetes or the Shiny server within the pod manages memory? Or is there a specific configuration or practice to enforce strict memory usage in such scenarios?

I'm looking for insights or solutions that could help manage the pod's memory usage more effectively, ensuring stability and performance akin to its local execution. Any advice or experiences with similar issues would be greatly appreciated.

I configured the memory limits and requests for the pod, expecting these settings to cap the memory usage of my Shiny app. I set the limits to a value I thought would be sufficient for the calculations (16GB, 24GB, 32GB), anticipating that the app would manage its memory usage within these limits.

Comment: "Ensure" would be to strong of a word here, but splitting your Shiny App into a dispatcher and task runners, potentially combined with[HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) usually does the trick. Add in a message queue for good measure to divide the tasks between your runners and Bob's your uncle. I would add a full blown answer, but my R-foo is as good as my Swaheli - both do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to deploy [shinylive](https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/shinylive.html) images for [loadbalancing](https://github.com/analythium/shiny-load-balancing#py-shiny-app) purposes if I got the docs right, it uses python + webassembly for web browser access.